# Adding email sending option in sharepoint online site

Tags: email, sharepoint, subscription, office365, sharepoint-online

I am creating a website in **sharepoint online office 365**. I want to add a **subscription module** in this website so that an email can be sent to user as well as admin. Can any one help me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

## Hi

Can this be helpfull, just add the fields that u want..
[Contact Us Form](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/add-a-contact-us-form-app-to-your-website-HA102845395.aspx)

Comment: Sorry Contact Us does not allow to send email to both user and admin both.